# LXML can't parse transitional XHTML 1.0 schema

Tags: python, xml, xsd, xhtml, lxml

I use the latest version (4.1.1) of `lxml` library to validate XHTML documents against [XHTML Transitional Schema](https://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd), but I'm getting a strange error as `lxml` is throws a strange error while parsing the XML schema which is clearly valid.

Does anybody have any ideas about why this error could be happening?

Here is my code:

```
In [1]: import lxml.etree

In [2]: schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(file='xhtml1-loose.xsd')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XMLSchemaParseError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d29a13bdd5f3> in <module>()
----> 1 schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(file='xhtml1-loose.xsd')

src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__ (src/lxml/etree.c:204036)()

XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)))).
```

p.s.
I took `xhtml1-loose.xsd` file from the [official source](https://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd) from w3.org.

Comment: Interesting, parsing `xhtml1-transitional.xsd` schema worked for me on both lxml 3.8.0 and 4.1.1.

Comment: @alecxe, interesting, could you please say, which versions of `libxml2` and `libxslt` do you have installed?

Comment: From what I see, I've got `libxml` 2.9.4, `libxslt` 1.1.29 (MacOS). Let me see what happens if I upgrade them.